# Passing data into django forms

Tags: python, django

```
class Test(forms.Form):

    def set_choices(self, choices):
        self.choices = choices

    def get_choices(self):
        return self.choices

    options  = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_choices())

f = Test()
f.set_choices(...)
```

Why isn't this possible?
How else can I achieve the goal of passing data into class Test?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read thoroughly through the docs? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a basic Python issue. You need to think about the order these commands are executed in, and their scope.

First, you define a form class called Test. That class has three attributes: a `set_choices` method, a `get_choices` method, and an `options` field. These definitions are evaluated when the class itself is defined. The definition of `options` calls `get_choices()`. However, there is no `get_choices` method in scope at that point, because the class is not yet defined.

Even if you somehow managed to sort out the scope issue, this would still not do what you want, because the definition of choices for `options`  is done at define time. Even if you later call `set_choices`, `options` still has the value of `get_choices` that was returned when the field was defined.

So, what do you actually want to do? It seems like you want to set dynamic choices on the `options` field. So, you should override the `__init__` method and define them there.

```
class Test(forms.Form):
    options = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('choices', None)
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if choices is not None:
            self.fields['options'].choices = choices
```

Comment: So how do you pass these choices in when using the Test form in the view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But you should certainly ask a new question, rather than commenting on a five-year-old answer.

Answer (score 0):

Extending `__init__` is a good way to add options to `ChoiceField` dynamically as Daniel Roseman  explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744327/passing-data-into-django-forms/5744438#5744438).

Just to add to that ... adding options at run time is hackish (at best). Here is the note about best practices (straight from [Django ChoiceField documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#field-choices)) -

> Finally, note that choices can be any
>   iterable object -- not necessarily a
>   list or tuple. This lets you construct
>   choices dynamically. But if you find
>   yourself hacking choices to be
>   dynamic, you're probably better off
>   using a proper database table with a
>   ForeignKey. choices is meant for
>   static data that doesn't change much,
>   if ever.